# Vue-JS: use variable in v-for as label in q-btn?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list:

`myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I want to use this list to create buttons and the label should be the number:

```
<q-btn v-for="number in myList" v-bind:key="number" color="primary" label="******" />
```

I want it to set the numbers in label. So I should have 9 buttons with different labels:

```
<q-btn color="primary" label="1" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="2" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="3" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="4" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="5" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="6" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="7" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="8" />
<q-btn color="primary" label="9" />
```

I am new in this... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is just numbers, you could iterate through number directly inside the `v-for` then bind that number to `label` prop :

```html
<q-btn v-for="number in 9" v-bind:key="number" color="primary" :label="number" />
```

Note that `:label="number"` is a shorthand of `v-bind:label="number"`